# Not able to execute script using sh <file_name>

Tags: scripts, sh

I am Not able to execute script using sh file_name
But it's working fine with command : ./filename

Rgrds
Aditya

Comment: `sh file_name` won''t work if the name of the file is **filename** not file_name.

Comment: Use `sh ./filename` instead of `sh file_name`

Comment: What do you mean by _"not able to execute"_? What message do you get?

Comment: I tried it's not working...

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, `sh` (or more accurately, `/bin/sh`) is ["dash"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash) and not "bash". When you use `sh {filename}` you force the script to be interpreted by `dash`. When you use `./filename` the script is interpreted by whatever the "shebang" (`#!...` on first line) says, and this is normally the interpreter the script has been written for (`bash`, likely).